# ¿ Cómo añadir un proyecto html5 a una aplicación creada con Cordova y que funcione?

Tags: javascript, html5, cordova, motor-de-juego

He creado un proyecto en Cordova siguiendo los  pasos  por defecto.
La aplicación corre en el dispositivo, pero cuando añado mi proyecto a la carpeta /www, sustituyendo el código generado por Cordova en los archivos de esa carpeta, por el código de este juego, al crear la app en el dispositivo no se ve el contenido del juego.
He buscado en las guías de Cordova, pero no encuentro solución a mi problema, no se si podrá ser algún plugin que no instalo, o algún error en el código.
En local el juego funciona perfectamente, les muestro el código y vean.
Debo decir que el proyecto extraído de Codepen del usuario @dissimulate.
¿ Pueden ver ustedes donde tengo el error ?
Gracias

```js
var Clarity = function () {

  this.alert_errors   = false;
  this.log_info       = true;
  this.tile_size      = 16;
  this.limit_viewport = false;
  this.jump_switch    = 0;
  
  this.viewport = {
      x: 200,
      y: 200
  };
  
  this.camera = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
  };
  
  this.key = {
      left: false,
      right: false,
      up: false
  };

  this.player = {

      loc: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
      },
      
      vel: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
      },
      
      can_jump: true
  };

  window.onkeydown = this.keydown.bind(this);
  window.onkeyup   = this.keyup.bind(this);
};

Clarity.prototype.error = function (message) {

  if (this.alert_errors) alert(message);
  if (this.log_info) console.log(message);
};

Clarity.prototype.log = function (message) {

  if (this.log_info) console.log(message);
};

Clarity.prototype.set_viewport = function (x, y) {

  this.viewport.x = x;
  this.viewport.y = y;
};

Clarity.prototype.keydown = function (e) {

  var _this = this;

  switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 37:
      _this.key.left = true;
      break;
  case 38:
      _this.key.up = true;
      break;
  case 39:
      _this.key.right = true;
      break;
  }
};

Clarity.prototype.keyup = function (e) {

  var _this = this;

  switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 37:
      _this.key.left = false;
      break;
  case 38:
      _this.key.up = false;
      break;
  case 39:
      _this.key.right = false;
      break;
  }
};

Clarity.prototype.load_map = function (map) {

  if (typeof map      === 'undefined'
   || typeof map.data === 'undefined'
   || typeof map.keys === 'undefined') {

      this.error('Error: Invalid map data!');

      return false;
  }

  this.current_map = map;

  this.current_map.background = map.background || '#333';
  this.current_map.gravity = map.gravity || {x: 0, y: 0.3};
  this.tile_size = map.tile_size || 16;

  var _this = this;
  
  this.current_map.width = 0;
  this.current_map.height = 0;

  map.keys.forEach(function (key) {

      map.data.forEach(function (row, y) {
          
          _this.current_map.height = Math.max(_this.current_map.height, y);

          row.forEach(function (tile, x) {
              
              _this.current_map.width = Math.max(_this.current_map.width, x);

              if (tile == key.id)
                  _this.current_map.data[y][x] = key;
          });
      });
  });
  
  this.current_map.width_p = this.current_map.width * this.tile_size;
  this.current_map.height_p = this.current_map.height * this.tile_size;

  this.player.loc.x = map.player.x * this.tile_size || 0;
  this.player.loc.y = map.player.y * this.tile_size || 0;
  this.player.colour = map.player.colour || '#000';
  
  this.camera = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
  };
  
  this.player.vel = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
  };

  this.log('Successfully loaded map data.');

  return true;
};

Clarity.prototype.get_tile = function (x, y) {

  return (this.current_map.data[y] && this.current_map.data[y][x]) ? this.current_map.data[y][x] : 0;
};

Clarity.prototype.draw_tile = function (x, y, tile, context) {

  if (!tile || !tile.colour) return;

  context.fillStyle = tile.colour;
  context.fillRect(
      x,
      y,
      this.tile_size,
      this.tile_size
  );
};

Clarity.prototype.draw_map = function (context, fore) {

  for (var y = 0; y < this.current_map.data.length; y++) {

      for (var x = 0; x < this.current_map.data[y].length; x++) {

          if ((!fore && !this.current_map.data[y][x].fore) || (fore && this.current_map.data[y][x].fore)) {

              var t_x = (x * this.tile_size) - this.camera.x;
              var t_y = (y * this.tile_size) - this.camera.y;
              
              if(t_x < -this.tile_size
              || t_y < -this.tile_size
              || t_x > this.viewport.x
              || t_y > this.viewport.y) continue;
              
              this.draw_tile(
                  t_x,
                  t_y,
                  this.current_map.data[y][x],
                  context
              );
          }
      }
  }

  if (!fore) this.draw_map(context, true);
};

Clarity.prototype.move_player = function () {

  var tX = this.player.loc.x + this.player.vel.x;
  var tY = this.player.loc.y + this.player.vel.y;

  var offset = Math.round((this.tile_size / 2) - 1);

  var tile = this.get_tile(
      Math.round(this.player.loc.x / this.tile_size),
      Math.round(this.player.loc.y / this.tile_size)
  );
   
  if(tile.gravity) {
      
      this.player.vel.x += tile.gravity.x;
      this.player.vel.y += tile.gravity.y;
      
  } else {
      
      this.player.vel.x += this.current_map.gravity.x;
      this.player.vel.y += this.current_map.gravity.y;
  }
  
  if (tile.friction) {

      this.player.vel.x *= tile.friction.x;
      this.player.vel.y *= tile.friction.y;
  }

  var t_y_up   = Math.floor(tY / this.tile_size);
  var t_y_down = Math.ceil(tY / this.tile_size);
  var y_near1  = Math.round((this.player.loc.y - offset) / this.tile_size);
  var y_near2  = Math.round((this.player.loc.y + offset) / this.tile_size);

  var t_x_left  = Math.floor(tX / this.tile_size);
  var t_x_right = Math.ceil(tX / this.tile_size);
  var x_near1   = Math.round((this.player.loc.x - offset) / this.tile_size);
  var x_near2   = Math.round((this.player.loc.x + offset) / this.tile_size);

  var top1    = this.get_tile(x_near1, t_y_up);
  var top2    = this.get_tile(x_near2, t_y_up);
  var bottom1 = this.get_tile(x_near1, t_y_down);
  var bottom2 = this.get_tile(x_near2, t_y_down);
  var left1   = this.get_tile(t_x_left, y_near1);
  var left2   = this.get_tile(t_x_left, y_near2);
  var right1  = this.get_tile(t_x_right, y_near1);
  var right2  = this.get_tile(t_x_right, y_near2);


  if (tile.jump && this.jump_switch > 15) {

      this.player.can_jump = true;
      
      this.jump_switch = 0;
      
  } else this.jump_switch++;
  
  this.player.vel.x = Math.min(Math.max(this.player.vel.x, -this.current_map.vel_limit.x), this.current_map.vel_limit.x);
  this.player.vel.y = Math.min(Math.max(this.player.vel.y, -this.current_map.vel_limit.y), this.current_map.vel_limit.y);
  
  this.player.loc.x += this.player.vel.x;
  this.player.loc.y += this.player.vel.y;
  
  this.player.vel.x *= .9;
  
  if (left1.solid || left2.solid || right1.solid || right2.solid) {

      /* fix overlap */

      while (this.get_tile(Math.floor(this.player.loc.x / this.tile_size), y_near1).solid
          || this.get_tile(Math.floor(this.player.loc.x / this.tile_size), y_near2).solid)
          this.player.loc.x += 0.1;

      while (this.get_tile(Math.ceil(this.player.loc.x / this.tile_size), y_near1).solid
          || this.get_tile(Math.ceil(this.player.loc.x / this.tile_size), y_near2).solid)
          this.player.loc.x -= 0.1;

      /* tile bounce */

      var bounce = 0;

      if (left1.solid && left1.bounce > bounce) bounce = left1.bounce;
      if (left2.solid && left2.bounce > bounce) bounce = left2.bounce;
      if (right1.solid && right1.bounce > bounce) bounce = right1.bounce;
      if (right2.solid && right2.bounce > bounce) bounce = right2.bounce;

      this.player.vel.x *= -bounce || 0;
      
  }
  
  if (top1.solid || top2.solid || bottom1.solid || bottom2.solid) {

      /* fix overlap */
      
      while (this.get_tile(x_near1, Math.floor(this.player.loc.y / this.tile_size)).solid
          || this.get_tile(x_near2, Math.floor(this.player.loc.y / this.tile_size)).solid)
          this.player.loc.y += 0.1;

      while (this.get_tile(x_near1, Math.ceil(this.player.loc.y / this.tile_size)).solid
          || this.get_tile(x_near2, Math.ceil(this.player.loc.y / this.tile_size)).solid)
          this.player.loc.y -= 0.1;

      /* tile bounce */
      
      var bounce = 0;
      
      if (top1.solid && top1.bounce > bounce) bounce = top1.bounce;
      if (top2.solid && top2.bounce > bounce) bounce = top2.bounce;
      if (bottom1.solid && bottom1.bounce > bounce) bounce = bottom1.bounce;
      if (bottom2.solid && bottom2.bounce > bounce) bounce = bottom2.bounce;
      
      this.player.vel.y *= -bounce || 0;

      if ((bottom1.solid || bottom2.solid) && !tile.jump) {
          
          this.player.on_floor = true;
          this.player.can_jump = true;
      }
      
  }
  
  // adjust camera

  var c_x = Math.round(this.player.loc.x - this.viewport.x/2);
  var c_y = Math.round(this.player.loc.y - this.viewport.y/2);
  var x_dif = Math.abs(c_x - this.camera.x);
  var y_dif = Math.abs(c_y - this.camera.y);
  
  if(x_dif > 5) {
      
      var mag = Math.round(Math.max(1, x_dif * 0.1));
  
      if(c_x != this.camera.x) {
          
          this.camera.x += c_x > this.camera.x ? mag : -mag;
          
          if(this.limit_viewport) {
              
              this.camera.x = 
                  Math.min(
                      this.current_map.width_p - this.viewport.x + this.tile_size,
                      this.camera.x
                  );
              
              this.camera.x = 
                  Math.max(
                      0,
                      this.camera.x
                  );
          }
      }
  }
  
  if(y_dif > 5) {
      
      var mag = Math.round(Math.max(1, y_dif * 0.1));
      
      if(c_y != this.camera.y) {
          
          this.camera.y += c_y > this.camera.y ? mag : -mag;
      
          if(this.limit_viewport) {
              
              this.camera.y = 
                  Math.min(
                      this.current_map.height_p - this.viewport.y + this.tile_size,
                      this.camera.y
                  );
              
              this.camera.y = 
                  Math.max(
                      0,
                      this.camera.y
                  );
          }
      }
  }
  
  if(this.last_tile != tile.id && tile.script) {
  
      eval(this.current_map.scripts[tile.script]);
  }
  
  this.last_tile = tile.id;
};

Clarity.prototype.update_player = function () {

  if (this.key.left) {

      if (this.player.vel.x > -this.current_map.vel_limit.x)
          this.player.vel.x -= this.current_map.movement_speed.left;
  }

  if (this.key.up) {

      if (this.player.can_jump && this.player.vel.y > -this.current_map.vel_limit.y) {
          
          this.player.vel.y -= this.current_map.movement_speed.jump;
          this.player.can_jump = false;
      }
  }

  if (this.key.right) {

      if (this.player.vel.x < this.current_map.vel_limit.x)
          this.player.vel.x += this.current_map.movement_speed.left;
  }

  this.move_player();
};

Clarity.prototype.draw_player = function (context) {

  context.fillStyle = this.player.colour;

  context.beginPath();

  context.arc(
      this.player.loc.x + this.tile_size / 2 - this.camera.x,
      this.player.loc.y + this.tile_size / 2 - this.camera.y,
      this.tile_size / 2 - 1,
      0,
      Math.PI * 2
  );

  context.fill();
};

Clarity.prototype.update = function () {

  this.update_player();
};

Clarity.prototype.draw = function (context) {

  this.draw_map(context, false);
  this.draw_player(context);
};
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background: #f2f2f2;
}

canvas {
 display: block;
 margin: 40px auto 20px;
 border: 1px solid #333;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 box-shadow: 0 0 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

p {
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: #777;
 display: block;
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.info {
 margin: 14px auto;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #999;
}

label {
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #555;
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <p> Use las teclas de flecha izquierda, derecha y arriba para moverse.</p>
    <p class="info">
        Los datos del mapa son totalmente personalizables y 
        programables (todos contenidos dentro de la variable "mapa"). 
        Vea los comentarios en el código para obtener instrucciones.
    </p>

    <label for="viewport">
        <input type="checkbox" id="viewport" onclick="game.limit_viewport=this.checked;" checked/> Confinar viewport al mapa</label>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.requestAnimFrame =
            window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(callback) {
                return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.width = 400;
        canvas.height = 400;
        
        /* Customisable map data */
        /* Datos de mapas personalizables */

        var map = {
        
            tile_size: 16,

            keys: [
                {id: 0, colour: '#333', solid: 0},
                {id: 1, colour: '#888', solid: 0},
                {id: 2,colour: '#555',solid: 1,bounce: 0.35},
                {id: 3,colour: 'rgba(121, 220, 242, 0.4)',friction: {x: 0.9,y: 0.9},gravity: {x: 0,y: 0.1},jump: 1,fore: 1},
                {id: 4,colour: '#777',jump: 1},
                {id: 5,colour: '#E373FA',solid: 1,bounce: 1.1},
                {id: 6,colour: '#666',solid: 1,bounce: 0},
                {id: 7,colour: '#73C6FA',solid: 0,script: 'change_colour'},
                {id: 8,colour: '#FADF73',solid: 0,script: 'next_level'},
                {id: 9,colour: '#C93232',solid: 0,script: 'death'},
                {id: 10,colour: '#555',solid: 1},
                {id: 11,colour: '#0FF',solid: 0,script: 'unlock'}
            ],
        
            /* An array representing the map tiles. Each number corresponds to a key */
            data: [
                [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2],
                [2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
            ],
            gravity: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0.3
            },
        
            vel_limit: {
                x: 2,
                y: 16
            },           
            movement_speed: {
                jump: 6,
                left: 0.3,
                right: 0.3
            },      
            player: {
                x: 2,
                y: 2,
                colour: '#FF9900'
            },       
            scripts: {
                change_colour: 'this.player.colour = "#"+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);',
                next_level: 'alert("Yay! You won! Reloading map.");this.load_map(map);',
                death: 'alert("You died!");this.load_map(map);',
                unlock: 'this.current_map.keys[10].solid = 0;this.current_map.keys[10].colour = "#888";'
            }
        };    
        var game = new Clarity();
        game.set_viewport(canvas.width, canvas.height);
        game.load_map(map);       
        game.limit_viewport = true;

        var Loop = function() {

            ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            game.update();
            game.draw(ctx);

            window.requestAnimFrame(Loop);
        };

        /* Start */
        
        Loop();
        
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cordova es una plataforma diferente, es cierto que puedes transformar a cordova, html y js, pero para poder que funcione tengo entendido que tendrás que hacer unos pequeños cambios adaptativos al código.... no estoy seguro, pero para que lo tengas en cuenta...